# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: terminate RDS then fail to update application version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I created AWS EB environments with RDS MySQL DB 1st time. But, I realized that I don't need to use MySQL so, I switched to sqlite3 and terminate RDS MySQL DB. After this, I can't update application version by using `git aws.push`. AWS EB shows the below error message all the time.

```
Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-xxxxxx-stack' aborted operation. 
Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to update: [AWSEBAutoScalingGroup].

Updating Auto Scaling group failed Reason: Template error: DBInstance xxxxxxx doesn't exist
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you deleted your RDS instance manually, Elastic BeansTalk does not know about that change and must be updated too.

You can go to Elastic Beanstalk console, pick up your Application and your Environment, go to "Configuration" and delete your RDS instance from the Elastic Beanstalk configuration.

Comment: How? There is no option to delete RDS instance.

Comment: Check the DeleteDBInstance or the equivalent in the web console  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteDBInstance.html

Comment: oh, we can delete the instance from rds, but its still shown in beanstalk, the issue is removing rds from beanstalk configuration.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  On ElasticBeanstalk legacy environment, it is only possible to attach a DB configuration to an environment.  DB life cycle is not handled by ElasticBeanstalk. On new environment ElasticBeanstalk can manage the life cycle of your database. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg//using-features.deployment.newapp.html

Comment: I am not using Legacy environment(I checked as per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg//using-features.migration.html#using-features.migration-proc), still there is no option to delete the RDS instance from beanstalk.

Answer (score 3):

As some have noted, you actually cannot manually delete your RDS instance from an elasticbeanstalk environment.

Per another answer you can change this via some options using one of the aws apis:[AWS Elastic Beanstalk change RDS Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663753/aws-elastic-beanstalk-change-rds-endpoint)

My solution was to terminate the environment and just start a new one from a saved configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to terminate an EB environment of mine due to previously having manually deleted the RDS instance associated with the environment.

I was able to solve this issue by creating a new RDS instance with the same identifier as the deleted instance, then terminating the environment like normal.