# How to change RDS instance for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set up my Elastic Beanstalk environment and allowed it to created the RDS instance associated with it.

Now, I want to change the database instance to another instance, but how do I do so while maintaining the RDS endpoint?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWS Elastic Beanstalk change RDS Endpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663753/aws-elastic-beanstalk-change-rds-endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're connecting to instance A and want to change it to instance  B, while maintaining the DB endpoint.

You can do it like this:

1. Snapshot instance B with `aws rds create-db-snapshot`.
2. Delete instance A with `aws rds delete-db-instance`.
3. Restore A using the snapshot from B using `aws rds restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot`.